# Tesseract recognising a single italic 1 as 17

Tags: c++, tesseract

I am using Tesseract to analyze some documents and ran into the issue that Tesseract seems to recognize italic characters multiple times.
The code itself looks about like this (abbreviated from a Wrapper class):

```
std::string recognise(const cv::Mat pageImage)
{
std::unique_ptr<tesseract::TessBaseAPI> tesseract = std::make_unique<tesseract::TessBaseAPI>();
tesseract->Init(tessDataDir.c_str(), LANGUAGE, tesseract::OEM_LSTM_ONLY);
  tesseract->SetImage(
    pageImage.data,
    pageImage.cols,
    pageImage.rows,
    CHANNELS_PER_PIXEL,
    static_cast<int>(pageImage.step));
static constexpr auto DPI = 300;
tesseract->SetSourceResolution(DPI);

// wrap char* in string and then delete the char*
auto *recognisedText_ptr = tesseract->GetUTF8Text();
std::string recognisedText{ recognisedText_ptr };
spdlog::debug("Recognised Text: {}", recognisedText);
delete[] recognisedText_ptr;

return recognisedText;
}
```

If i feed this image:

[image: Image containing the Text: ""01A15, 01A15R" in italics]

tesseract recognises `07A715, 071A15R,`. I can see how it mistakes the first 1 for a 7 however I don't understand how it parses the second "01A" for "071A".

I tried using user patterns but to no help.
What else can I do to improve the recognition?

Comment: This may not solve your problem, but according to [this](https://zdenop.github.io/tesseract-doc/baseapi_8cpp_source.html#l00961), you failed to check for `NULL` being returned by `GetUTF8Text()`.  Thus `std::string recognisedText{ recognisedText_ptr };` will lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thank you I did only look at the header and missed that it can return a `nullptr`.